# Default parameter for Sass @mixin

Tags: css, sass, box-shadow

I can't seem to find an answer to this specific question on Stack Overflow anywhere.

I am using Compass and am building a `@mixin` for `box-shadow`/`text-shadow`.

I am wondering if it is possible to set a default parameter in Sass/SCSS?

Here is my current code:

```
@mixin outer-glow($color, $type) {
  @if $type == 'text' {
    @include text-shadow(0 0 2px #{$color});
    @include text-shadow(0 0 .125rem #{$color}); // 2px
  } @else {
    @include box-shadow(0 0 2px #{$color});
    @include box-shadow(0 0 .125rem #{$color}); // 2px
  }
}
```

I would like to use this `@mixin` and have it default to `box-shadow` if a `$type` is not declared:

```
// declaration
@include outer-glow($my-color);
// output
would compile to box-shadow

// declaration
@include outer-glow($my-color, text);
// output
would compile to text-shadow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [helpful post](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/810) that answered my question.

So I've edited my `@mixin` and now I am able to use it as I intended, with it defaulting to `box-shadow` if now parameter is assigned:

```
@mixin outer-glow($color, $type: box) {
  @if $type == 'text' {
    @include text-shadow(0 0 2px #{$color});
    @include text-shadow(0 0 .125rem #{$color}); // 2px
  } @else {
    @include box-shadow(0 0 2px #{$color});
    @include box-shadow(0 0 .125rem #{$color}); // 2px
  }
}
```